# How to perform Single click checkbox selection in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with first column as text column and second column as CheckBox column. What I want is, if I click the check box. It should get checked.
But, it takes two click to get selected, for first click the cell is getting selected, for the second clicks the check box is getting checked. How to make the check box to get checked/unchecked with a single click.

I'm using WPF 4.0. Columns in the DataGrid are AutoGenerated.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225836/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-how-do-you-turn-selection-off, but this one has better title

Answer (score 228):

For single click DataGrid checkbox you can just put regular checkbox control inside `DataGridTemplateColumn` and set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: WOW - I'm glad I read to the end. This works perfectly and is considerably less complicated, IMO this should be marked as the answer.

Comment: This also works for ComboBox. As in: way, WAY better than DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Comment: It doesn't when i use space bar to check/uncheck and arrows to move to another cell.

Comment: I have interpreted this answer that you have to Bind "IsSelected", but thats **not true!** You can just use `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` with **your own Binding** and it will work!!

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32692759/2964949) of @weidian-huang helped me to understand that, thanks!

Answer (score 69):

I solved this with the following Style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

It's of course possible to adapt this further for specific columns ...

Comment: Nice. I changed it to a MultiTrigger and added a condition for ReadOnly=False but the basic approach worked for my simple case where keyboard navigation isn't important.

Comment: Adding that style to my grid raise an exception of Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: I've resolved using a trigger on DataGridRow and not the cell and forcing IsSelected to true when mouse is over, it is not the best approach, but it works.

Comment: This is the cleanest way I've seen so far! Nice! (for IsReadOnly="True" a MultiTrigger will do the job)

Comment: This solution has some unexpected/unwanted behaviour. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39004317/2881450

Comment: For the binding to work, you will need a UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: Thanks @AQuirky - this comment was essential for me.

Answer (score 35):

First of, I know this is a pretty old question but I still thought I'd try and answer it.

I had the same problem a couple of days ago and came across a surprisingly short solution for it (see [this blog](http://tapiocacom.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/checkbox-on-datagrid-with-single-click.html)). Basically, all you need to do is replace the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` definition in your XAML with the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyCheckBoxColumnHeader">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyViewModelProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The upside of this solution is obvious - it's XAML-only; thus it effectively refrains your from burdening your code-behind with additional UI logic.

Comment: This is similar to Konstantin Salavatov's answer and this one worked for me.  +1 for including the code sample where his did not.  Thanks for a good answer to an old question.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you do it with combobox columns, the little dropdown button will be visible for all cells in that column, all the time. Not just when you click on the cell.

Comment: This still requires 2 clicks for me

Comment: I figured it out. You can't use this solution in conjunction with certain DataGrid configuations like `DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridCell_Selected" SelectionUnit="Cell"`

Answer (score 23):

To make [Konstantin Salavatov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7270548/149265) work with `AutoGenerateColumns`, add an event handler to the `DataGrid`'s `AutoGeneratingColumn` with the following code:

```
if (e.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn && !e.Column.IsReadOnly)
{
    var checkboxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
    checkboxFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    checkboxFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
    checkboxFactory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName) { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            Header = e.Column.Header,
            CellTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = checkboxFactory },
            SortMemberPath = e.Column.SortMemberPath
        };
}
```

This will make all of `DataGrid`'s auto-generated checkbox columns be "single click" editable.

Comment: Thanks for filling in an autogenerated column approach, this handily points me in a suitable direction.

Comment: Thank you for this! In .NET 7,  `ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty` is not available, so I changed it to `CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty`

Answer (score 18):

Based on blog referenced in Goblin's answer, but modified to work in .NET 4.0 and with Row-Selection Mode.

Notice that it also speeds up DataGridComboBoxColumn editing - by entering edit mode and displaying dropdown on single click or text input.

XAML:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput" />
        </Style>
```

Code-behind:

```
    private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        GridColumnFastEdit(cell, e);
    }

    private void DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        GridColumnFastEdit(cell, e);
    }

    private static void GridColumnFastEdit(DataGridCell cell, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cell == null || cell.IsEditing || cell.IsReadOnly)
            return;

        DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return;

        if (!cell.IsFocused)
        {
            cell.Focus();
        }

        if (cell.Content is CheckBox)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
            {
                if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    cell.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                {
                    row.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ComboBox cb = cell.Content as ComboBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                //DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
                dataGrid.BeginEdit(e);
                cell.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                 DispatcherPriority.Background,
                 new Action(delegate { }));
                cb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }


    private static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement parent = element;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me. My bound ViewModel was not updating with the other solutions.

Comment: @surfen, Is I need to put the above style and the code in every page and its codebehind, if I have many pages which has datagrid in it.Is it possible to use the style and code in a common place instead of creating it in every page

Comment: Why do you need to dispatch an empty Action?

Comment: @user3690202 It's like DoEvents in Windows.Forms. After calling BeginEdit you need to wait for the cell to actually enter the edit mode.

Comment: @JiříSkála - I don't recall ever needing to do this in my solutions to this problem, but I understand what you are saying - thanks!

Comment: This works great for the Checkbox, but messes with my DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged() handler...  The handler is called _not_ when a combobox is clicked, but when it is clicked a 2nd time.

Comment: Tried to add this programatically via a style:     
`cellStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DataGridCell.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(CheckBoxDataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));`    
  
The handler is called, but the cell.Content is ContentPresenter, and I can't find the CheckBox.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

There is a much simpler solution here.

```
          <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="20" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If you use `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` to implement, first click is to focus, second click is to check.

But using `DataGridTemplateColumn` to implement needs one click only.

The difference of using `DataGridComboboxBoxColumn` and implementation by `DataGridTemplateColumn` is also similar.

Comment: Good explanation for me and worked instantly, thanks!

Comment: With the solution, hitting the space bar to check/unckeck doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 12):

Yet another simple solution is to add this style to your DataGridColumn.The body of your style can be empty.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
     <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
           </Style>
     </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Pressing the space bar to check / uncheck will move the CheckBox from the left to the middle. Adding <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/> in the style will prevent the CheckBox from moving.

Comment: Great solution, but why does it work ? An explanation would be appreciated. Does it work also for other DataGridXxxColumns ?

Comment: This should be the top. So simple yet the most effective out of all of them

Answer (score 11):

Base on *Jim Adorno* answer and comments on his post, this is solution with `MultiTrigger`:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 10):

I've tried these suggestions, and plenty of others I've found on other sites, but none of them quite worked for me.  In the end, I created the following solution.

I've created my own DataGrid-inherited control, and simply added this code to it:

```
public class DataGridWithNavigation : Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
{
    public DataGridWithNavigation()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGridCell), 
            DataGridCell.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown));
    }


    private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
        {
          DependencyObject obj = FindFirstControlInChildren(cell, "CheckBox");
            if (obj != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox cb = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)obj;
                cb.Focus();
                cb.IsChecked = !cb.IsChecked;
            }
        }
    }

    public DependencyObject FindFirstControlInChildren(DependencyObject obj, string controlType)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        // Get a list of all occurrences of a particular type of control (eg "CheckBox") 
        IEnumerable<DependencyObject> ctrls = FindInVisualTreeDown(obj, controlType);
        if (ctrls.Count() == 0)
            return null;

        return ctrls.First();
    }

    public IEnumerable<DependencyObject> FindInVisualTreeDown(DependencyObject obj, string type)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj.GetType().ToString().EndsWith(type))
            {
                yield return obj;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                foreach (var child in FindInVisualTreeDown(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i), type))
                {
                    if (child != null)
                    {
                        yield return child;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

What does all this do ?

Well, each time we click on any cell in our DataGrid, we see if the cell contains a CheckBox control within it.  If it *does*, then we'll set the focus to that CheckBox *and toggle it's value*.

This seems to work for me, and is a nice, easily reusable solution.

It is disappointing that we *need* to write code to do this though.  The explanation that the first mouse click (on a DataGrid's CheckBox) is "ignored" as WPF uses it to put the row into Edit mode might sound logical, but in the real-world, this goes against the way every real application works.

If a user sees a checkbox on their screen, they should be able to click on it once to tick/untick it.  End of story.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a bunch of "solutions", but this is the first that seems to really work every time. And it fits beautifully into my application architecture.

Comment: This solution results in issues updating the binding, whereas the one here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing does not.

Comment: too complicated. see my answer. :)

Comment: After 5 years this code still saving time for social life :) For some simple requirements, @KonstantinSalavatov solution is enough. In my case I mixed my code with Mike's solution to achieve dynamic event association with handlers, my grid have dynamic number of columns, with one click in specific cell must store in the database the changes.

Answer (score 8):

I solved with this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox Height="25">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TheProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The checkbox active on single click!

Comment: I did not need to wrap the Checkbox in a ViewBox, but this answer worked for me.

Comment: This to me is a much cleaner solution than the accepted answer. No need for Viewbox either. Funny how this works better than the defined Checkbox column.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="StilCelula" TargetType="DataGridCell"> 
<Style.Triggers>
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="IsEditing" 
     Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
     Converter={StaticResource CheckBoxColumnToEditingConvertor}}" />
 </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
<Style>
```

```vb
Imports System.Globalization
Public Class CheckBoxColumnToEditingConvertor
    Implements IValueConverter
    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Try

            Return TypeOf TryCast(value, DataGridCell).Column Is DataGridCheckBoxColumn
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Visibility.Collapsed
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an approach with an own column class that is based on the default DataGridCheckBoxColumn class and can be used like the normal one. Just copy/paste.

```
public class DataGridCheckBoxColumn : System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCheckBoxColumn
{
    private static Style _noFocusEditElementStyle;

    static DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
    {
        ElementStyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridCheckBoxColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(NoFocusEditElementStyle));
        EditingElementStyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridCheckBoxColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(NoFocusEditElementStyle));
    }


    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if (e.Property.Name == nameof(IsReadOnly))
        {
            ElementStyle = IsReadOnly ? DefaultElementStyle : NoFocusEditElementStyle;
            EditingElementStyle = IsReadOnly ? DefaultElementStyle : NoFocusEditElementStyle;
        }
    }

    public static Style NoFocusEditElementStyle
    {
        get
        {
            if (_noFocusEditElementStyle == null)
            {
                Style style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox));

                // When not in edit mode, the end-user should not be able to toggle the state
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(UIElement.FocusableProperty, false));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Top));

                style.Seal();
                _noFocusEditElementStyle = style;
            }

            return _noFocusEditElementStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage with Read/Write Property:

```
<myNamespace:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Name"
                    Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Usage with ReadOnly Property:

```
<myNamespace:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Name"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Explanation:

- The default column class has two style properties one for the edit mode and one for the view.
- In case of ReadOnly we use the view style in both cases
- In the other case in the edit mode we set the edit style
- Instead of EditElementStyle I prefered a style where the checkbox does not get the focus (NoFocusEditElementStyle) since this behavior looks a little weird