# DataGrid 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view when dragging multiple items

Tags: wpf, datagrid, invalidoperationexception

I have a datagrid which gets data like this:

```
    public struct MyData
    {
        public string name { set; get; }
        public string artist { set; get; }
        public string location { set; get; }
    }

    DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    col4.Binding = new Binding("name");
    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col1);
    dataGrid1.Items.Add((new MyData() { name = "Song1", artist = "MyName", location =     "loc"}));
    dataGrid1.Items.Add((new MyData() { name = "Song2", artist = "MyName", location =     "loc2"}));
```

The problem is- whenever a user tries to edit a cell or drags multiple cells- the app throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

Why is this? Is it because of the way the data is entered?
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using a `struct` use a `class` instead.

UPDATED ANSWER: Try adding your MyData instances to a List then assigning that list to the DataGrid.ItemsSource

Comment: I changed the 'struct' to 'class', but it still throws the exception.

Comment: @amitarios: Try adding your `MyData` instances to a `List<MyData>` then assigning that list to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`

Comment: Putting it into a list edited the list but not the source object. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12):

I got this issue when assigning ItemsSource to IEnumerable<T>.

I fixed it by converting the IEnumberable<T> to a List<T> and then assigning that to ItemsSource.

I'm not sure why using IEnumerable caused that issue, but this change fixed it for me.

Comment: Because `List<T>` supports `Add()` and `Remove()`

Comment: Agreed Jack Frost.

Answer (score 2):

If you use datagrid DataGridCheckBoxColumn you need to set `<Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="true" />`
on check box column. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244451/1643201

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not my own, just the working code example suggested by AnthonyWJones.

```
public class MyData //Use class instead of struct
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string artist { set; get; }
    public string location { set; get; }
}

DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
col4.Binding = new Binding("name");
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col1);
dataGrid1.Items.Add((new MyData() { name = "Song1", artist = "MyName", location =     "loc"}));
dataGrid1.Items.Add((new MyData() { name = "Song2", artist = "MyName", location =     "loc2"}));

//Create a list of MyData instances
List<MyData> myDataItems = new List<MyData>(); 
myDataItems.Add(new MyData() { name = "Song1", artist = "MyName", location =     "loc"});
myDataItems.Add(new MyData() { name = "Song2", artist = "MyName", location =     "loc2"});

//Assign the list to the datagrid's ItemsSource
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case,

```
processLimits.OrderBy(c => c.Parameter);
```

returns an

```
IOrderedEnumerable<ProcessLimits>
```

not a

```
List<ProcessLimits>
```

so when I assign a style for my event setter to a checkbox column in my datagrid

```
style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ServiceActiveChecked)));
```

ServiceActiveChecked is never called and I got

```
'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.
```

and for anyone else doing checkboxes in datagrid columns, I use a column object with my column data in this constructor for adding the data grid I use with adding the style above.

```
datagridName.Columns.Add(new DataGridCheckBoxColumn()
                            {
                                Header = column.HeaderText.Trim(),
                                Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(column.BindingDataName.Trim()) { StringFormat = column.StringFormat != null ? column.StringFormat.Trim().ToString() : "" },
                                IsReadOnly = column.IsReadOnlyColumn,
                                Width = new DataGridLength(column.DataGridWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star),
                                CellStyle = style,
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the datagrid's source after the InitializeComponent:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FilterGrid.ItemsSource = ScrapeFilter;
    }
```