# DataGridComboBoxColumn - Auto drop down on single click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGridComboBoxColum in a DataGrid.
I would like to be able to click on the cell one time and have the combobox drop down. Currently I have to click multiple times.

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,85,0,0" Name ="dg_display" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="645"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="DgDisplaySelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Symbol" Binding="{Binding Symbol}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Company ID" Binding="{Binding CompanyID}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Sector" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Sector}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [0]}" Visibility="Visible" >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SectorList}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SectorList}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you need the `DataGrid` to go into edit mode, i.e. raising the BeginningEditEvent?

Comment: I never raise the beginningeditevent. Do i need to?

Comment: The first click on a cell is setting focus on the cell and (maybe) selecting it (depends on the SelectionMode of the `DataGrid`), the second click is showing the EditingElement and that's when the BeginningEditEvent is raised (by the `DataGrid`). So I understand that you're not handling this event, nor your logic is dependent whether the `DataGrid` is in edit mode (i.e. whether IsEditingCurrentCell == true or IsEditingRowItem == true), right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One-click DataGridComboBoxColumn editing + one click CheckboxColumn editing

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333704/724944

XAML:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput" />
        </Style>
```

Code-behind:

```
    private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        GridColumnFastEdit(cell, e);
    }

    private void DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        GridColumnFastEdit(cell, e);
    }

    private static void GridColumnFastEdit(DataGridCell cell, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cell == null || cell.IsEditing || cell.IsReadOnly)
            return;

        DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return;

        if (!cell.IsFocused)
        {
            cell.Focus();
        }

        if (cell.Content is CheckBox)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
            {
                if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    cell.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                {
                    row.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ComboBox cb = cell.Content as ComboBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                //DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
                dataGrid.BeginEdit(e);
                cell.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                 DispatcherPriority.Background,
                 new Action(delegate { }));
                cb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }


    private static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement parent = element;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The "See also" is how to do it. Use a DataGridTemplateColumn and set its CellTemplate to a ComboBox.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of the other answers worked for me. What did work for me though was the following.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
    Header="Example ComboBox"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValuePath="Id">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I don't remember where I got this solution. It's possible it came from stack overflow. If someone sees an original source, feel free to post a comment.

Comment: It works partly. I got 2 clicks instead of 3 clicks :(

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with @surfen's answer, probably because it's many years later and WPF has probably changed quite a bit. It seems `DataGrid` now takes care of some things for you, like editing a text field automatically when you start typing.

I use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` for my combo box column. The template has a `TextBlock` for its `CellTemplate`. The call to `BeginEdit` followed by the dispatcher call causes the combo box to appear in the visual tree. It then appears that the mouse click is sent to the combo box and it opens by itself.

Here's my modified version of @surfen's code:

```
public static class DataGridExtensions
{
    public static void FastEdit(this DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        dataGrid.ThrowIfNull(nameof(dataGrid));

        dataGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) => { FastEdit(args.OriginalSource, args); };
    }

    private static void FastEdit(object source, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var dataGridCell = (source as UIElement)?.FindVisualParent<DataGridCell>();

        if (dataGridCell == null || dataGridCell.IsEditing || dataGridCell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }

        var dataGrid = dataGridCell.FindVisualParent<DataGrid>();

        if (dataGrid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!dataGridCell.IsFocused)
        {
            dataGridCell.Focus();
        }

        if (dataGridCell.Content is CheckBox)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
            {
                if (!dataGridCell.IsSelected)
                {
                    dataGridCell.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var dataGridRow = dataGridCell.FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>();

                if (dataGridRow != null && !dataGridRow.IsSelected)
                {
                    dataGridRow.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataGrid.BeginEdit(args);

            dataGridCell.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));
        }
    }
}

public static class UIElementExtensions
{
    public static T FindVisualParent<T>(this UIElement element)
        where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement currentElement = element;

        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            var correctlyTyped = currentElement as T;

            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            currentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentElement) as UIElement;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What an extraordinary amount of code, just to save the user an intuitively needless click! I appreciate your effort, but I'm afraid my opinion of WPF has gone down again.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, eventually I came across this thread with Nathan's solution being the best solution so far. Yet it has the issue that if you single click on a combobox column, the dropdown is opened but the current value is not selected.

I finally solved that issue and ended up with less code. Note the DataTemplate makes use of the MouseLeftButtonDown event to initialize the "one click magic" in the UI code behind, thanks to @NathanAldenSr

A nice side effect of the template column solution is that the data source for the combobox items may change per row, i.e. each row may have a different set of combobox items available.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboBox (TemplateColumn)">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox 
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyComboBoxItems, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                       AncestorType=Window}}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding MyComboBoxValue, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                IsDropDownOpen="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding MyComboBoxValue, Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                Padding="3" 
                MouseLeftButtonDown="FastEditEvent" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The view code behind is making use of NathanAldenSr the extension methods code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FastEditEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var dataGridCell = (sender as UIElement)?.FindVisualParent<DataGridCell>();

        dataGridCell.FastEdit(args);
    }
}

public static class DataGridExtensions
{
    public static void FastEdit(this DataGridCell dataGridCell, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (dataGridCell == null || dataGridCell.IsEditing || dataGridCell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }

        var dataGrid = dataGridCell.FindVisualParent<DataGrid>();

        if (dataGrid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!dataGridCell.IsFocused)
        {
            dataGridCell.Focus();
        }

        dataGrid.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            dataGrid.BeginEdit(args);
        });
    }
}

public static class UiElementExtensions
{
    public static T FindVisualParent<T>(this UIElement element)
        where T : UIElement
    {
        var currentElement = element;

        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            if (currentElement is T correctlyTyped)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            currentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentElement) as UIElement;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```