# DatagridTemplate column content only visible when row selected and cell clicked

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Hi I have a `Datagrid` that is bound to an ObservableCollection of custom AutoCAD layer objects. 3 of the columns are DataGridTextColumns and work correctly. However I also have a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that contains a StackPanel containing a label and a `Rectangle`. I am using the label to display the ACI or RGB value of the layer depending how it is set and displaying the colour in the rectangle. The rectangle has a mouse down event that launches a colour picker dialog so the user can select a new colour for the layer. This functionality works. What doesn't work is that the contents of the cell (the label and rectangle) are only shown in a row that is selected and the cell clicked on whereas they need to be visible at all times.

I have tried using a Grid inside the DataTemplate and using the Grid's FocusManager.Focused element to give the Rectangle Focus but this hasn't changed the behaviour.

```
<t:DataGrid x:Name="layersGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLayer, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
       <t:DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="Visible">
          <t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=swatch}">
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <Label Content="{Binding Colour.ColourProperty}"/>
                           <Rectangle Name="swatch" Fill="{Binding Colour, Converter={StaticResource colourConverter}}"
                               MouseLeftButtonDown="swatch_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                   </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
          </t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     </t:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </t:DataGrid.Columns>
</t:DataGrid>
```

Additionally, once you change the colour of the layer in the model view, the rectangle hasn't updated until another row is selected and then the changed one is selected again.

```
private void swatch_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Colour col = LaunchColourPickerCode();
        ((LayersModel)this.Resources[MODEL]).SelectedLayer.Colour = col;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with them not displaying has been fixed by using `CellTemplate` instead of a `CellEditingTemplate`

I adapted surfen's answer on this page to solve the selection problem

[How to perform Single click checkbox selection in WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833536/how-to-perform-single-click-checkbox-selection-in-wpf-datagrid/4827377#4827377)

Replacing his method with this:

private static void GridColumnFastEdit(DataGridCell cell, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cell == null || cell.IsEditing || cell.IsReadOnly)
                return;

```
        DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return;

        if (!cell.IsFocused)
        {
            cell.Focus();
        }


        DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
        if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
        {
            row.IsSelected = true;
        }

    }
```

and adding an event on the swatch to obtain the cell it is in

private void swatch_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

```
        DataGridCell cell = null;

        while (cell == null)
        {
            cell = sender as DataGridCell;
            if (((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent != null)
                sender = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent;
            else
                sender = ((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
        }


        GridColumnFastEdit(cell, e);
    }
```

Also thanks to kmatyaszek