# How to fix DataGridCell PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to implement single-click checkboxes described in this article: http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

I have the style tag in my resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The code-behind event is also copied verbatim from the article.  I have a DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridSelectMusic" Margin="170.55,236.139,38,66.723" AutoGenerateColumns="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="DataGridSelectMusic_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp_1">
        <DataGrid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFD4D0C8" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </DataGrid.Background>
    </DataGrid>
```

The data binding for the data grid is in code-behind.

The problem is that clicking a DataGridCell within this DataGrid does not cause the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event to fire.  Any ideas why this isn't happening?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you've got `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`, so it behaves a little differently.  In this case, I believe you need to handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` and the `AutoGeneratedColumn` events and wire up the handler manually.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/26/wpf-datagrid-working-with-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) to see how to do that.  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833536/how-to-perform-single-click-checkbox-selection-in-wpf-datagrid) addresses the same issue, and scroll down through the answers to see different options for handling it with auto-generated columns.