# How to disable row selection and enable checkbox in one click?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to create a datagrid in WPF MVVM that have rows with information and Columns is a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` that represent `Boolean` property.

I want to be able to click on a check box and and changes it to 'checked' in one click.
I also want to disable the option to select rows and also to disable the option to change something else in the other columns.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using this answer as a starting point: [How to perform Single click checkbox selection in WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833536/how-to-perform-single-click-checkbox-selection-in-wpf-datagrid)

I did some modifications and wound up with this:

WPF:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridRow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void DataGridRow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        if (row == null) return;
        if (row.IsEditing) return;
        if (!row.IsSelected) row.IsSelected = true; // you can't select a single cell in full row select mode, so instead we have to select the whole row
    }

    private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null) return;
        if (cell.IsEditing) return;
        if (!cell.IsFocused) cell.Focus(); // you CAN focus on a single cell in full row select mode, and in fact you HAVE to if you want single click editing.
        //if (!cell.IsSelected) cell.IsSelected = true; --> can't do this with full row select.  You HAVE to do this for single cell selection mode.
    }
```

Try that out and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridCheckBoxColumn works by default in this way. First click selects the row or cell and the second click changes the checkbox state. It is sometimes desired: for example when you need to call selection changed event before you use the checkbox.
In order to create a checkbox column where checkboxes change on first click it is better to use DataGridTemplateColumn with CheckBox as a cell template:

```
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ChBoxColumn">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```