# Easiest way to click a Checkbox in a DataGrid for C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridShortcuts" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFADB5B9" Margin="0,0,0,47">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

when I click the row (any cell), how can I enable/disable the checkbox in the 2nd column?

Currently I have to double click and I read several articles that discuss the first click puts it into editing mode and the second click checks it.

I've also tried

```
        Style rowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
        rowStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DataGridRow.MouseDoubleClickEvent,
                                 new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_DoubleClick)));
        dataGridShortcuts.RowStyle = rowStyle;
```

and this didn't work either.

Comment: When the row goes into Edit mode, does it fire any events?  If so, trap that one and ignore the mouse.

Comment: That will also put you closer to the goal of (I presume) "enabling the checkbox when the row is selected" by not limiting the method of row selection to using the mouse.

Comment: I am confused about your statement. Can you show me sample code?

Comment: Think about this: why are you pushing your user to use the mouse to select the row, thereby enabling the checkbox?  What if they want to use arrow keys and the spacebar?  What if they're disabled and need to use alternative input?  Write your code so that it targets *what you want to do* rather than *how you imagine your users doing it*.

Comment: For cross-reference: the solution to this question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7270548/3336376

Answer (score 0):

[This should answer your question](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/27/more-datagrid-samples-custom-sorting-drag-and-drop-of-rows-column-selection-and-single-click-editing.aspx), even if I think mouse event handling is the wrong way to go about it.