# How to stop DataGrid row color from changing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I've implemented code to get around the double click issue when selecting a row in a WPF DataGrid. I'm using the following code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5857908/40106.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Rows have alternating colors. The problem is when I mouse over a row, in one column, the light blue color is replaced by white.

The above code works great except for this one issue. How do I stop the color from changing when mousing over a row?

I have tried the following but it doesn't have any effect:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
             <Setter Property="Background" Value"AliceBlue" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the cell will display it's edit style when you hover the mouse above the cell.

For a `DataGridTextColumn` this means, that a `TextBox` with a white background is displayed.

You can set a Style to `<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>` and set the Background to `transparent`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

To get the white Background, when actually editing the cell you could add another trigger to the IsSelected event:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

Another option would be to apply the DataGridCell Style to CheckBoxColumns only. For other Column types it wouldn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: I tried the first code and it works except the cells depress when you hover over them.  Some type of animation. Is there a way to remove that? Also, for checkboxes, when hovering over a colored row, the checkbox changes to the row color (not the actual cell).  Is there a way to make the checkbox stay white?

Comment: Should also set `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>` for the TextBox style to prevent a change in height.

Comment: For the checkboxes it look like their default MouseOver behavior.

Comment: Much better. TextBox text still shifts slightly when mousing over it. Is there a way to remove that behavior?

Comment: In my example it looked good. But setting the Margin to 0 might help. There might be some Margin/Padding/Border that causes this effect.