# How to perform Single click checkbox selection in WPF DataGrid with IEditableObject object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel

The default behavior of DataGridCheckBoxColumn is that the user has to click twice to change the checkbox value. In the [How to perform Single click checkbox selection in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833536/how-to-perform-single-click-checkbox-selection-in-wpf-datagrid) topic there are a couple of solutions which work, but there is a problem - is you have a viewmodel object in code behind, which implements the `IEditableObject` interface, then the `EndEdit` method doesn't execute.

Any idea how to make single click work and also preserve the `IEditableObject` functionallity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could handle the `GotFocus` event for the `DataGrid` and explicitly enter the edit mode and check/uncheck the `CheckBox`:

```
private void dg_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null && cell.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn)
    {
        dg.BeginEdit();
        CheckBox chkBox = cell.Content as CheckBox;
        if (chkBox != null)
        {
            chkBox.IsChecked = !chkBox.IsChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GotFocus="dg_GotFocus">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

to use same method for all checkbox

```
private void GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sen = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
            if (cell != null && cell.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn)
            {
                sen.BeginEdit();
                CheckBox chkBox = cell.Content as CheckBox;
                if (chkBox != null)
                {
                    chkBox.IsChecked = !chkBox.IsChecked;
                }
            }
        }
```