# Toggle Checkbox value after validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to toggle the checkboxes in a DataGridCheckboxColumn if it has more than a certain number in another column.

So far, it loops through the DataGrid and succesfully validates the other column I need it to, but I cannot toggle any of the Chekboxes that meet the criteria.

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding cost}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check" IsReadOnly="False" Width="50">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style />
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

```cs
for(int i=0; i<dataGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if(Convert.ToDecimal(dataGrid.Columns[3].GetCellContent(i)) > 200)
        {            //Columns[3] is the "Total" Column.
             ((dataGrid.Columns[6]).GetCellContent(i) as CheckBox).IsChecked = true;
             //Columns[6] is the DataGridCheckBoxColumn
        }
}
```

I get the correct value for the Total column using:

```cs
dataGrid.Columns[3].GetCellContent(i)
```

But

```cs
((dataGrid.Columns[6]).GetCellContent(i) as CheckBox);
```

Which is the DataGridCheckBoxColumn, returns a nullException, even though it is the right column. If I WriteLine dataGrid.Columns[6], I get "System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCheckBoxColumn", so I'm sure I'm in the right place but I cannot set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` attribute to your DataGridCheckBoxColumn, like this:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check" IsReadOnly="False" Width="50" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    ...
```

Also you can check the following stack overflow question:
[How to perform Single click checkbox selection in WPF DataGrid with IEditableObject object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889566/how-to-perform-single-click-checkbox-selection-in-wpf-datagrid-with-ieditableobj/42891433)